# How to convert an Dom.XMLNode to its String representation

Tags: xmlnode

Is there a way to convert an XMLNode element to it's string representation?

So if my XMLNode is <div>testing</div>, and I want a string representation of the element and text "<div>testing</div>".

This question was asked before but a workaround was found before the answer could be given.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no library method for this, so you have to build a recursive node parser. From scratch. Hopefully someone's got something you can use.

Comment: Do you also have a `Dom.Document` instance? The `Document` class has a [toXmlString](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm%23apex_classes_xml_dom_document) method on it for this type of output but not for an individual node.